# Proving that $f(x)=\frac{1000x^{14}-7x^{11}+12x+7}{(x^7-1)^2+1}$ is a bounded function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I want to prove that function $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that:

$$f(x)=\frac{1000x^{14}-7x^{11}+12x+7}{(x^7-1)^2+1}$$

is bounded. A good place to start would be to check limits as x goes to $+\infty, -\infty$. Using elementary properties of limits you can show that both limits are equal to $1000$.

What left now is to prove that the function is convergent for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$. We can see that $f$ is continuous (it is sum and quotient of polynomials and denominator never reaches $0$). So here proof by contradiction seemed like a good idea:

Let's assume that $f$ is not bounded. Then for some $a\in\Bbb{R}$ we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+/-}} f(x) = +/- \infty$. But as we're in $\Bbb{R}$ we can choose $x,y$ such that $x<a<y$ and $f$ will be defined at interval $[x,y]$. And we would have $\sup f([x,y]) = +\infty$ or $\inf f([x,y]) = -\infty$ and by Stone-Weierstrass Theorem there should exist $a'\in [x,y]$ such that $f(a')=\inf f([x,y])$ or $f(a')=\inf f([x,y])$. So we have a contradiction. That means $f$ is bounded.

Is my proof correct? Is there an alternate way available?

Comment: *Convergent* and *Stone-Weierstrass* are not the names you want to use.

Comment: Leave out Stone, and change convergent for bounded, I guess. In the third paragraph the existence of $a$ follows, but you need to explain that it follows from the computation of the limits, and from certain interval you get from it being compact.

Comment: It's a basic result that a continuous function on a (nonempty) compact set achieves a minimum and a maximum. Use that to simplify the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way: since $(x^7-1)^2+1$ never vanishes, $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)=1000$, for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $f(x)$ is between $999$ and $1001$ on the complement of $[-M,M]$. Since $I=[-M,M]$ is a closed interval and $f$ is a continuous function, $f$ is bounded on $I$. Since it is bounded also on the complement of $I$, $f$ is everywhere bounded.